# My Dialog.show() not work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am making a loading effect when calling MainActivity. I have no idea why my Dialog.show is not working in the AsyncTask. All i just see the just the instant when it dismiss, but the dialog never appear before that. 
Thank you.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new LoadViewTask().execute(); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
....}



private class LoadViewTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() { 
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Loading...","Loading application View, please wait...", false, false);  

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        try 
        {
            synchronized (this) 
            {
                int counter = 0;
                while(counter <= 4)
                {
                    this.wait(1000);
                                            counter++;
                    publishProgress(counter*25);
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) 
    {
        progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
    {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }


}
```

Comment: your code is working my side can post your full activity code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use FragmentDialogs for using dialogs in Android.

Here it is well explained:

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the content view before starting your async task:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set the content view first
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new LoadViewTask().execute(); 
....}
```

Comment: @DannyHo I have tested your code on my Android 2.3.3 and Android 4.1.2 devices, and the dialog appeared and disappeared correctly on both devices. Could you please give us more details, may be full code of your `MainActivity` too?

Comment: actually i tested it will work properly on Android 2.3.3 but not 4.1.2. And the reminding code in my mainactivity is a  HttpPostHandler , do u think the problem cause by this?

Comment: @DannyHo I cannot make wild guesses until I see the actual code, sorry :)

Comment: Oh, i think i misunderstand something, should i put the httprequest in the DoInBackground in Asynctask instead of Oncreate???